# CS0104: 'Scripts' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.WebPages.Scripts' and 'System.Web.Optimization.Scripts'

Tags: reference, ambiguous

My project is on MVC 4. 
In it I can't access any of scripts function like @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") as Scripts is an ambigious reference between 'System.Web.WebPages.Scripts' and 'System.Web.Optimization.Scripts'

I have following entries in my webconfig :

```
<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="Product360"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

I updated System.web.optimization from package manager console, still it's showing me same error.

I can't figure out why it's intellisensing in System.web.WebPages instead of System.web.optimization.

Anyone has any updates on this?

Comment: how did you solve it ? I have the same issue now

Answer (score 0):

Do you use WebMaxtrix / Web Pages or only ASP.NET MVC? If you're only using MVC get rid of this line

```
<add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
```

And you shouldn't have a conflict anymore.

**Note**: you might need to restart Visual Studio for the namespaces to be handled properly in the cshtml files after the modification.

Comment: Gabriel, I don't have above entry in webconfig which is at view levels of MVC. Entries which I have mentioned in question are at project level. And even if I commented that I still have same error

Comment: You're having issues using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")` in a cshtml file, is that right? Could you paste the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section of the ./Views/Web.config?